# How do I solve Jmeter Error Connection reset?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I am running a performance test on a site using Jmeter. Using a load of up to 100 simultaneous users(Threads) the tests pass perfectly, trying to raise this load to 300 users (Threads) I get the following error:

> Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException / Non HTTP response message: Connection reset

The error occurs in only 0.68% of requests (out of 2412 requests made by 300 users(Threads) only 2 requests generated this error)

I thought it was the maximum number of connections allowed on my server, I went to my application's webconfig and entered the following information: "Min Pool Size = 5; Max Pool Size = 500;". but still not solve the problem.

Does anyone know what I can do to not generate these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it indicates a problem with your application, try checking:

- application logs
- application/web server logs and configuration
- underlying operating system logs and networking configuration. also pay attention to number of open ports/sockets/handles (can be checked using either built-in OS monitoring tools or [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/))

---

If you're absolutely sure that there is nothing wrong with your test script and application and [JMeter is configured to behave exactly like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) you can follow instructions from [JMeterSocketClosed](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed) wiki page

More information: [The Mysteries of Connection Close](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/http-the-definitive/1565925092/ch04s07.html)